# C# Animation and music at the same time

Tags: c#, animation, audio-player

I write the program in the console, at startup, first play the music, and then the animation. Help make animation and music at the same time. Rummaged through the Internet and found nothing

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Media;
using System.Threading;

namespace Animation_and_music
{
    class animation
    {
        public void music()
        {
            SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer("C:\\audio.wav");
            player.PlaySync();
        }
        public void gif()
        {
            Console.SetWindowSize(102, 49);
            Image image = Image.FromFile(@"1.gif");
            FrameDimension dimension = new FrameDimension(image.FrameDimensionsList[0]);
            int frameCount = image.GetFrameCount(dimension);
            StringBuilder sb;

            int left = Console.WindowLeft, top = Console.WindowTop;

            char[] chars = { '#', '#', '@', '%', '=', '+', '*', ':', '-', '.', ' ' };

            for (int i = 0; ; i = (i + 1) % frameCount)
            {
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                image.SelectActiveFrame(dimension, i);

                for (int h = 0; h < image.Height; h++)
                {
                    for (int w = 0; w < image.Width; w++)
                    {
                        Color cl = ((Bitmap)image).GetPixel(w, h);
                        int gray = (cl.R + cl.R + cl.B) / 3;
                        int index = (gray * (chars.Length - 1)) / 255;

                        sb.Append(chars[index]);
                    }
                    sb.Append('\n');
                }

                Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
                Console.Write(sb.ToString());

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        }

        static Image ScaleImage(Image source, int width, int height)
        {
            Image dest = new Bitmap(width, height);
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(dest))
            {
                gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, width, height);
                gr.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

                float srcwidth = source.Width;
                float srcheight = source.Height;
                float dstwidth = width;
                float dstheight = height;

                if (srcwidth <= dstwidth && srcheight <= dstheight)
                {
                    int left = (width - source.Width) / 2;
                    int top = (height - source.Height) / 2;
                    gr.DrawImage(source, left, top, source.Width, source.Height);
                }
                else if (srcwidth / srcheight > dstwidth * dstheight)
                {
                    float cy = srcheight / srcwidth * dstwidth;
                    float top = ((float)dstheight - cy) / 2.0f;
                    if (top < 1.0f) top = 0;
                    gr.DrawImage(source, 0, top, dstwidth, cy);
                }
                else
                {
                    float cx = srcwidth / srcheight * dstheight;
                    float left = ((float)dstwidth - cx) / 2.0f;
                    if (left < 1.0f) left = 0;
                    gr.DrawImage(source, 0, left, cx, dstheight);
                }
                return dest;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

"static void Main(string[] args)" is in another code

Thanks in advance for your help
(Sorry for my english, I use a translator)

Comment: Try `player.Play();` in your `music` method instead of `player.PlaySync();`. If this fixes your problem I'll be happy to post an answer explaining why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your trying to do two things at the same time in only one thread, which is impossible, one thread can only do one thing at a time. You need to use multiple threads to achieve your goal, which in this case is simple enough just use `player.Play();` instead of `player.PlaySync();`.
`player.Play();` automatically starts a new thread and runs the task there.

[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_multithreading.htm) is a good tutorial/ introduction to threads in C#

Answer (score 0):

As @MindSwipe said you need to use more threads.

Example:

```
class Animation
{
 public Animation
 {
Thread mythread = new Thread(DoSomething);
Thread mythread2 = new Thread(DoSomething2);
mythread.Start();
mythread2.Start();
 }

public void DoSomething()
{
Do_gif_animation();
}
public void DoSomething2()
{
Do_music();
}

}
```